# Unable to initialize a window and wait for a process to end in Python 3 + GTK+ 3

Tags: linux, python-3.x, subprocess, gtk3

I'm new to object-oriented programming, Python and GTK+3, though I have a decent knowledge of procedural programming (mainly C).

I'm trying to build a simple Python + GTK+ 3 script to run `pkexec apt-get update` under Linux.

I have a `mainWindow` class (based on a `Gtk.Window` class) which contains a button object named `button` (based on a `Gtk.Button` class) which triggers a `new_update_window()` method defined in `mainWindow` upon a `clicked` event;

The `new_update_window()` method initializes an `updateWindow` object from an `updateWindow` class (based on a `Gtk.Window` class) which contains a label object named `label` (based on a `Gtk.Label` class) and calls the methods `show_all()` and `update()` defined in `updateWindow`;

The `update()` method is supposed to change `label`, run `pkexec apt-get update` and change `label` again.

The problem is no matter what I do one of the following occurs:

- If I run `subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])` directly, `update.Window` is shown but `label` is set immediately to the value it should be set only after `pkexec apt-get update` has finished executing;
- If I run `subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])` directly, `update.Window` is not shown until `pkexec apt-get update` has finished executing;
- I tried `import`ing `threading`, defining a separate `run_update()` method in `updateWindow` and start the function in a separate thread using `thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_update)`, `thread.start()`, `thread.join()`, but still depending on which method I call in `run_update()` (`subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen`) the relative behavior described above exhibits.

## Tl;dr

I'm at a loss to understand how to accomplish what I'm after, which is:

1. Showing `updateWindow` (`Gtk.Window`)
2. Updating `label` (`Gtk.Label`) in `updateWindow`
3. Running `pkexec apt-get update`
4. Updating `label` in `updateWindow`

- `subprocess.Popen()`: `update.Window` is shown but `label` is set immediately to the value it should be set only after `pkexec apt-get update` has finished executing;
- `subprocess.call()`: `update.Window` is not shown until `pkexec apt-get update` has finished executing;
- Wrapping either of the two in function and run the function in a separate thread doesn't change anything.

Here's the code;

Not using a thread (case 1, in this case using `subprocess.Popen()`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk
import subprocess

class mainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updater")

        button = Gtk.Button()
        button.set_label("Update")
        button.connect("clicked", self.new_update_window)
        self.add(button)

    def new_update_window(self, button):
        update = updateWindow()
        update.show_all()
        update.update()

class updateWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updating...")

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Idling...")
        self.add(self.label)

    def update(self):
        self.label.set_text("Updating... Please wait.")
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])
        self.label.set_text("Updated.")

    def run_update(self):

main = mainWindow()
main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
main.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Using a thread (case 3, in this case using `subprocess.Popen()`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk
import threading
import subprocess

class mainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updater")

        button = Gtk.Button()
        button.set_label("Update")
        button.connect("clicked", self.new_update_window)
        self.add(button)

    def new_update_window(self, button):
        update = updateWindow()
        update.show_all()
        update.update()

class updateWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updating...")

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Idling...")
        self.add(self.label)

    def update(self):
        self.label.set_text("Updating... Please wait.")
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_update)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        self.label.set_text("Updated.")

    def run_update(self):
        subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])

main = mainWindow()
main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
main.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: `thread.join()` will wait until `run_update` has finished, that is probably not intended.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Updated so that it makes more sense. The point of `thread.join()` was to wait `run_update()` to finish before triggering `self.label.set_text("Updated.")`, but what actually happens is it *doesn't* wait for `run_update()` to finish and just goes ahead and executes `self.label.set_text("Updated.")` (i.e.: I can see the label reporting "Updated." while `pkexec apt-get update` is still running).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Python's `subprocess` module, you could use [`Gio.Subprocess`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gio-2.0/classes/Subprocess.html) which integrates with GTK's main loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

# ...

class updateWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Updating...")

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Idling...")
        self.add(self.label)

    def update(self):
        self.label.set_text("Updating... Please wait.")
        subprocess = Gio.Subprocess.new(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"], 0)
        subprocess.wait_check_async(None, self._on_update_finished)

    def _on_update_finished(self, subprocess, result):
        subprocess.wait_check_finish(result)
        self.label.set_text("Updated.")
```

Comment: This seems the "right" way to do it, thanks. I would have sent an edit, but it's way too short and I don't want to clutter the answer unusefully: the `Gio.Subprocess.new() method` expects at least one `Gio.SubprocessFlags` after `argv`, so one is needed in order to make the snippet work: `Gio.Subprocess.new(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"], 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there...
and the solution pretty simple :)

The issue you are having is that `subprocess.call()` would freeze the GUI (loop), and thus prevent the window to appear, while `subprocess.Popen()` would throw out the command and jump to `self.label.set_text("Updated.")`

#### How to solve

You can simply solve it by running a separate thread, calling your command:

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])
```

and move the label- change command

```
self.label.set_text("Updated.")
```

into the thread, positioned *after* the first command. The thread then does not freeze the interface, while `label` is not changed too early, since `subprocess.call()` will prevent that.

The code then becomes:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk
from threading import Thread
import subprocess

class mainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updater")

        button = Gtk.Button()
        button.set_label("Update")
        button.connect("clicked", self.new_update_window)
        self.add(button)

    def new_update_window(self, button):
        update = updateWindow()
        update.show_all()
        update.update()

class updateWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updating...")

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Idling...")
        self.add(self.label)

    def update(self):
        self.label.set_text("Updating... Please wait.")
        Thread(target = self.run_update).start()

    def run_update(self):
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])
        self.label.set_text("Updated.")

main = mainWindow()
main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
main.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

#### Alternatively

If you'd like to avoid using `Thread`, you could use `Gtk.main_iteration()` to prevent the interface from freezing while the process runs:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk
import subprocess

class mainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updater")

        button = Gtk.Button()
        button.set_label("Update")
        button.connect("clicked", self.new_update_window)
        self.add(button)

    def new_update_window(self, button):
        update = updateWindow()
        update.show_all()
        update.update()

class updateWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updating...")

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Idling...")
        self.add(self.label)

    def update(self):
        self.label.set_text("Updating... Please wait.")
        subprocess.Popen(["gedit"])
        self.hold()
        self.label.set_text("Updated.")

    def run_update(self):
        subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])

    def hold(self):
        while True:
            Gtk.main_iteration()
            try:
                subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "apt-get"]).decode("utf-8")
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                break

main = mainWindow()
main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
main.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

---

#### EDIT

Ongoing insight learned there is a better way to use threads then posted above in my answer.

You can use threads in a `Gtk` GUI, using

```
GObject.threads_init()
```

Then, to update the interface *from* the thread, use

```
GObject.idle_add()
```

from [this (slgihtly outdated) link](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=edit&file=faq20.006.htp):

*...call `gobject.threads_init()` at application initialization. Then you launch your threads normally, but make sure the threads never do any GUI tasks directly. Instead, you use `gobject.idle_add` to schedule GUI task to executed in the main thread*

When we replace `gobject.threads_init()` by `GObject.threads_init()` and `gobject.idle_add` by `GObject.idle_add()`, we pretty much have the updated version of how to run threads in a Gtk application.

Applied in your code (using second example, using threads):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
from threading import Thread
import subprocess

class mainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updater")

        button = Gtk.Button()
        button.set_label("Update")
        button.connect("clicked", self.new_update_window)
        self.add(button)

    def new_update_window(self, button):
        update = updateWindow()
        update.show_all()
        update.update()

class updateWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updating...")

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Idling...")
        self.add(self.label)

    def update(self):
        # self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_update)
        thread = Thread(target=self.run_update)
        thread.start()

    def run_update(self):
        GObject.idle_add(
            self.label.set_text, "Updating... Please wait.",
            priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            )
        subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])
        GObject.idle_add(
            self.label.set_text, "Updated.",
            priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            )

GObject.threads_init()
main = mainWindow()
main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
main.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Your first solution with threads is not recommended, as you aren't supposed to modify the GUI from a thread other than the main one.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
def run_update(self):
    subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])
```

you are not waiting the process to terminate, try

```
def run_update(self):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "/usr/bin/apt-get", "update"])
    proc.wait()
```

instead. This should wait for the completion properly, but it won't help much since `updateWindow.update` will be called from `mainWindow.new_update_window` and GUI thread will be waiting for the process to complete.

Custom signals can be used to communicate when the process started by `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.call` completes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
import threading
import subprocess

class mainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updater")

        button = Gtk.Button()
        button.set_label("Update")
        button.connect("clicked", self.new_update_window)
        self.add(button)

    def new_update_window(self, button):
        update = updateWindow(self)
        update.show_all()
        update.start_update()

class updateWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Updating...")

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Idling...")
        self.add(self.label)
        self.parent = parent

        GObject.signal_new('update_complete', self, GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST,
                           None, (int,))
        self.connect('update_complete', self.on_update_complete)

    def on_update_complete(self, widget, rc):
        self.label.set_text("Updated {:d}".format(rc))
        # emit a signal to mainwindow if needed, self.parent.emit(...)

    def start_update(self):
        self.label.set_text("Updating... Please wait.")
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_update)
        thread.start()

    def run_update(self):
        rc = subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/pkexec", "apt-get", "update"],
                                shell=False)
        self.emit('update_complete', rc)

main = mainWindow()
main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
main.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to help. I tried this, now the window is not shown, `pkexec`'s prompt sticks on the screen after having entered the password and only upon closing it manually the window shows up, but as before the label is changed already even though `apt-get` is still running. This both by calling the function directly and by letting the function be called in a new thread as in the second example. `subprocess.Popen()` seems to be letting the execution continue regardless, in the same way `subprocess.call()` seems to block it.

Comment: Didn't see your update on the answer, thanks, that works.